# Turning individual cells of DataGridView into Combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

Environment: Web Development in Visual Studio
Language: ASP.NET

I'm afraid I already know the answer, but it can't hurt to ask. I have an application that gets data from SAP and can return specific results or a list of possible results for each row of a DataGridView. So the user might enter "abcd" and get "1234" as a result or he might get "1234 or 2345 or 3456" as a result. For each row I would like to have each column where multiple results were returned as a combobox. The rest should stay fixed though, since having the table littered with comboboxes that only have one result would be annoying.

Is there any trick to do this? I know you can "convert" an entire column into a column of comboboxes using DataGridViewComboBoxColumn like in this blog:
http://mytactics.blogspot.de/2014/01/convert-datagridview-column-to-combo-box.html
.Is there any way to have a combobox only for specific cells though? I know I could put a combobox next to each row of the table and let the user choose from that one or I could have a combox in every single row and maybe lock the ones with only one result. I'm not happy about either of those solutions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and add a ComboBox to `yourDataGridViewCell.Controls` and make the `label.Visible = false;` or remove it. It would be something like:

```
yourDataGridViewCell.Controls.Clear();
yourDataGridViewCell.Controls.Add(new ComboBox());
yourDataGridViewCell.Controls[0].DataSource = yourList;
//set the value member etc.
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! And here I thought it would be a pain in the ass to get this working.